# ajax request not running success funciton

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function:

```
function loadRoles(){
console.log("load roles");
var data = {
  "fn" : "rLoad",
  "projectID" : sProject,
  "ajax" : "true"
};
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: SERVICE_URL, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
  data: data,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(response) {
    var i, list, tList;
        console.log("responding");
        lsRoles = response;

        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            //list += formatCheckBoxItem(response[i]);
            tList += formatListItem(response[i].name[0], response[i].id[0]);
        }
        console.log(tList);  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////         list has the text "undefined" at the start of it... i cannot work out why 0.o
        //$("#cbProjects").html(list).trigger("create");
        $("#lsRoles").html(tList).listview('refresh');
  }
});
}success: function(response) {
    alert("The project " + name + " has been added and can be viewed in the QLearn App");
  }
});
}
```

i know that sProject is defined

my problem is that the `success` option never runs, or at least, it's not getting to  `console.log("responding");`

i am getting a `200` response from the server....

i don't know what else could be a problem here. thoughts?

Comment: yeh, i encode the data to JSON when i send it back to client, i've seen the result aswell it's JSON

Comment: What happens if you switch to `$.get`? `$.get( SERVICE_URL, getdata, function() { alert( "success" ); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have kind of solved this, i took the success out of the request and changed the line that called `loadRoles()` to:

```
loadroles().done(function(response{
   console.log(response)
})
.fail(function(response){
    console.log(response)
});
```

now i am able to display response in the log, however it is the `.fail()` that is sending the response

response looks like this now: `readyState: 4, responseText: "[{"id":{"0":"projectM"},"name":{"0":"Project Manager"}}]", status: 200, statusText: "OK"`

it works, so... meh! but if anyone can suggest why it's running `fail()` i'd be greatful

Answer (score 1):

Catch the error-callback too and check its parameters.

Is SERVICE_URL the same domain? (same origin policy)

What does the network-tab of the browser-developer-tools show as the answer?

One way to get a useful error-message is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: SERVICE_URL,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Note that if you declare the response to be JSON, the request will fail, if the response is not valid JSON. In your case you'll have to remove "adultScotland" to have valid JSON.

Comment: the response from the server is: status code: `200 OK` -- the URL is a different domain but this isn't a problem anywhere else in the app. in the network tab it says `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` under `Response Headers` -- the response looks like this: `adultScotland[{"id":{"0":"projectM"},"name":{"0":"Project Manager"}}]` --- which is the expected result

Comment: Looks like you're using CORS, see "CORS from JQuery" here: [http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Comment: sorry, i was thinking about a different app, all the files relating to this problem are on the same server

Answer (score 0):

You use `+=` and on the first run your string is not string yet. So it tries to compute this on the first run:

```
undefined + 'some string'
```

Initialize your list as an empty string first:

```
var i, list, tList = "";
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't solve my main concern which is it never seems to even run that part of the code

Comment: did you read `my problem is that the success option never runs, or at least, it's not getting to console.log("responding");`?

Comment: i don't see why everyone is down voting this, he helped me with a problem i had decided to solve later (i had that same problem throughout my app)